# MongoDB first time user setup

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-12.04

My friend has been dumped by a developer who was working on creating a web app for them. They have asked me for help but I have never used MongoDB.

1. To connect to a remote MongoDB do I need to install MongoDB on my EC2 instance? If yes, can you suggest a link that can show this step by step as I have never done this before. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2. Next is accessing the data, can someone point me to an example of scripting with MongoDB whereby I would execute an equivalent query to:

   ```
   SELECT field1, field2, SUM(field3)
   FROM table
   GROUP BY field1, field2
   ```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking us to allow them to get paid for us doing the work

Comment: Nice one man, please save your time in future. I am trying to help someone who said anything about money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is useful for translate  SQL to mongo querys http://www.querymongo.com